# Python single function launched with multiprocessing faster than simple call

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

It is quite complicated to report here the code I am using so I keep the question more on a theoretic level if possible.
I have a Python 3 function

```
def myworkfunction():
   # do stuff
```

I execute this function, only once, via Multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
starttime = time.time()
pointers = []
pointers.append(Process(target=myworkfunction, args=()))
for pointer in pointers:
  pointer.start()
for pointer in pointers:
  pointer.join()
print(time.time() - starttime) # it gives us 26 seconds
```

I execute the same function directly

```
starttime = time.time()
myworkfunction()
print(time.time() - starttime) # it gives us 35 seconds
```

What I get is that it is faster with Multiprocessing than executing directly the same function (26 seconds vs 35 seconds)

Without knowing what the function does, do you see any possible reason why it happens? Is Multiprocessing giving some kernel priority to the functions launched? Is there some cache or preloading that could explain what I see?

Thank you and cheers
Giacomo

I am expecting to have the same run time (or at least very-very close)

--------------------- UPDATE -------------------

The reason of this difference is the fact that my code runs under Flask which uses threads. So I guess that if I launch my function normally, the workload is executed in the same queue with Flask activities. While if I move the workload of the function in a different process I can run some code in parallel with Flask, saving time...
I have tested the same scenario excluding Flask and I get practically the same amount of time.
Thanks to AhmedAEK and all for the help!

Comment: Multiprocessing adds some extra work for scheduling and finishing each task. To make multiprocessing faster, the actual task should be significantly more substantial than this additional overhead.

Comment: @ÖmerSezer, they are reporting that multiprocessing makes a single call faster.

Comment: Are you using the `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom? Just curious.

Comment: I'd be intrigued to see absolute proof of this. Of course, it depends on what *myworkfunction()* actually does but there's an overhead in creating, starting and cleaning up a Process which can only add to the execution time

Comment: If you have other threads in your app, then the other process will generate a new GIL which can finish more work.

Comment: @JonSG: not sure if it helps but the "myworkfunction" is launched by a Flask server when a specific request is received. The Flask app is launched inside "if __name__ == '__main__':". 
I am sure no other calls are performed during the test.

Comment: @DarkKnight: as for the answer for JonSG, the entire code is a Flask server running on a ARM processor and the function does read/write on /dev/mem... it is not easy to prepare a simplified and reproducible code. What I can try is to exclude the Flask server behind and launch the function by myself in standalone or via Multiprocessing

Comment: @AhmedAEK maybe the fact the everything is running under Flask could be an explanation?

Comment: @giacomoc yes, flask uses threads.

Comment: @AhmedAEK ok I have run the test excluding Flask and the time of the two functions (with/without Processing) is the same, with s very small extra time in processing as suggested by DarkKnight. 
Definitely Flask is running something behind that is consuming CPU time... I was not expecting such a difference!
Thanks for the the suggestion, I will edit my message with the solution